# How to join subsequent digits in a Python list into a double (or more) digit number

Tags: python

I have the following string:

```
string = 'TAA15=ATT'
```

I make a list out of it:

```
string_list = list(string)
print(string_list)
```

and the result is:

```
['T', 'A', 'A', '1', '5','=', 'A', 'T', 'T']
```

I need to detect subsequent digits and join them into a single number, as shown below:

```
['T', 'A', 'A', '15','=', 'A', 'T', 'T']
```

I'm also quite concerned with performances. This string conversion is done thousand times.

Thank you for any hints you can provide.

Comment: Is your task to merge consecutive digits in a list of strings, or is your actual task to extract consecutive digits from a string? And concerning "I make a list out of it:" Where did the ``=`` go?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: merge consecutive digits. I forgot to write that I delete the '=' in the string before making a list. Thank you

Comment: Do you want the equal sign or not?In your question you aren't saying so but you accepted an answer with it. Is`=` always after the digits?

Comment: The equal sign is irrelevant for the sake of my question. I do not want to create confusion, since I accepted the answer with the "=" sign, so I edited the question by putting back the "=" in the string_list . Sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a very short solution

```
import re

def digitsMerger(source):
    return re.findall(r'\d+|.', source)
```

```
digitsMerger('TAA15=ATT')
['T', 'A', 'A', '15', '=', 'A', 'T', 'T']
```

Comment: FWIW, on my desktop this solution takes approximately 1/3 less time than the solution using itertools.groupby.

Comment: Really nice bu can you explain it? I mean is it matching a sequence of digits (which get put together) OR any other character?

Comment: The regex starts by looking for a digit, if it's found, it tries to get as many digits as possible. If it does not find any digit, it simply takes 1 character(`.` being the biggest wildcard, `\D` would have worked too to mean "anything except a digit")

Answer (score 6):

Using `itertools.groupby`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import groupby
string = 'TAA15=ATT'

result = []
for k, v in groupby(string, str.isdigit):
    if k:
        result.append("".join(v))
    else:
        result.extend(v)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['T', 'A', 'A', '15', '=', 'A', 'T', 'T']
```

Comment: Very nice. But it was sufficient and more efficient to say: `else: result.extend(v)` (no need to create the list).

Comment: Instead of `lambda x: x.isdigit()` use `str.isdigit`

Answer (score 3):

Another regexp:

```
import re

s = 'TAA15=ATT'

pattern = r'\d+|\D'

m = re.findall(pattern, s)

print(m)
```

Comment: I don't know if this can be described as a problem with SO or not (it's clearly not a problem for the OP who has posed the question) but the second question is posted there are often several people ready to jump on it. So, you work diligently to come up with a solution only to find that someone came up with essentially the same one a couple of minutes before you. Or some judge deems the question to be too similar to an already asked and answered question and you don't even get to post your work. I now find myself not bothering to answer new questions unless they've gone unanswered for a while.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson good point, I get your concern. I've just tried the answers which fit faster in my code, the accepted answer is short and fast. Once I've got what I needed I did not tried the other ones, that's not fair I understand.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson I know your point, yes, there are 3 types of Q on SO. 1st: meaningles (~20%). 2nd well defined, but not a real problem, like this (~50%) 3th: the real problems, which remain unanswered most of the cases... Somehow SO should filter this problem. Is there any meta thread which discuss this issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expressions, in Python the library `re`:

```
import re
string = 'TAA15=ATT'
num = re.sub('[^0-9,]', "", string)
pos = string.find(num)
str2 = re.sub('\\d+',"", string)
str2 = re.sub('=',"", str2)
print(str2)
l = list()
for el in str2:
    l.append(el)
l.insert(pos, num)
print(l)
```

Basically `re.sub('[^0-9,]', "", string)` is telling: take the string, match all the characters that are not (`^` means negation) numbers (`0-9`) and substitute them with the second parameter, ie., an empty string. So basically what's left are only digits that you have to convert to an integer.

If the `=` is always after the digit instead of

```
str2 = re.sub('\\d+',"", string)
str2 = re.sub('=',"", str2)
```

you can do

```
str2 = re.sub('\\d+=',"", string)
```

Comment: I do need to detect double digit numbers in the list but also modify the list with [.., '1', '5', ..] in order to get [.., '15', ..]

Comment: I modified the code in the answer: now it should work

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function that compares the last value seen and the next and use `functools.reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

string_list = ['T', 'A', 'A', '1', '5', 'A', 'T', 'T']

def combine_nums(lst, nxt):
    if lst and all(map(str.isdigit, (lst[-1], nxt))):
        nxt = lst[-1] + nxt
    return lst + [nxt]

print(reduce(combine_nums, string_list, [])
```

Results:

```
['T', 'A', 'A', '1', '15', 'A', 'T', 'T']
```